# Trigger css hover state change after transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got some UI that has javascript events that cause CSS changes that reposition elements in the UI. I'm having a problem with hover states, where the hover state doesn't update properly after these changes. I've boiled down a very simple example here.

1. hover "block 1" **Observe**: "block one" turns blue
2. click "block 1" **Observe**: css changes cause the blocks to flip
3. Observe: the mouse is now hovering "block 2" but "block 1" is still blue
4. Expected behavior: "block 2" should be blue after the transform and "block 1" should be red.
5. Observe: Moving the mouse very slightly causes them to "correct"

```js
$(function() {
    $('.block').click(function () {
       $('.container').toggleClass('flipped'); 
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 150px;
}

.container.flipped {
     transform: rotate(180deg);    
}

.block {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
}

.block:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">
        block 1
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        block 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to ensure that the hover state gets updated properly after classes are applied and changes occur?

Comment: I'm only really concerned about firefox and chrome with this simplified example, but a cross-browser solution is preferred.

Comment: Running in chrome, I can't reproduce the issue. I see the expected result.

Comment: Ok, so Chrome on windows doesn't seem to have the issue *in this example*. It's reproducible in IE 10, Chrome Mac, Firefox Mac. In my actual, real-life problem, unsimplified - I have the issue even in Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit of a hack. It doesn't work perfectly, but it gets the job done.

```
$(function() {
    $('.block').click(function () {
       $('.container').hide();
       $('.container').toggleClass('flipped');
       $('.container').show(0);
    });
});
```

Hiding the container, flipping it and then showing it again forces that portion of the page to be redrawn, which seems to trigger the `:hover` selector again.

**Note:** Passing `0` for the duration to `show()` seems to be necessary for this to work.

Here's a demo:

[**CodePen Link**](http://codepen.io/mroemore/pen/emravr)